# Devmode-engine-rust on Sawtooth running on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: consensus, hyperledger-sawtooth, dev-mode

I want to install devmode-engine-rust on Sawtooth 1.0.5 running on Ubuntu 16.04. Standard installation using apt-get gives:

```
sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust : 
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 8.3.0) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11 is to be installed 
Depends: libnorm1 (>= 1.5r6+dfsg1) but it is not installable 
Depends: libzmq5 (>= 4.2.5) but 4.1.4-7ubuntu0.1 is to be installed 
Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable 
Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable 
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is to be installed 
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:8.3.0) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Could not correct this one, so tried to compile from sources. Looks like compilation went OK. Now the question: what are correct directories where to copy compiled binaries and supporting files? Tried the simplest one - put devmode-engine-rust on the path, but that doesn't work.

Alternatively, if anybody knows how to solve the problem with

```
sudo apt-get install sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust
```

that would be great, too. Any suggestions on installing sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust are very welcome.

Thank you!

(I did find several stackoverflow articles on that, i.e. adding another depository and doing apt-get update, etc. None of them worked)

P.S. Here is what happens when I start different parts of sawtooth:
Window 1 - Validator:

```
$ sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-validator -vv --scheduler parallel
[sudo] password for ahg2009:
[2019-08-04 11:41:31.052 INFO     path] Loading path information from config: /etc/sawtooth/path.toml
[2019-08-04 11:41:31.058 INFO     validator] Loading validator information from config: /etc/sawtooth/validator.toml
[2019-08-04 11:41:31.076 INFO     path] Loading path information from config: /etc/sawtooth/path.toml
[2019-08-04 11:41:31.082 INFO     keys] Loading signing key: /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
[2019-08-04 11:41:31.109 INFO     cli] sawtooth-validator (Hyperledger Sawtooth) version 1.0.5
[2019-08-04 11:41:31.110 INFO     cli] config [path]: config_dir = "/etc/sawtooth"; config [path]: key_dir = "/etc/sawtooth/keys"; config [path]: data_dir = "/var/lib/sawtooth"; config [path]: log_dir = "/var/log/sawtooth"; config [path]: policy_dir = "/etc/sawtooth/policy" .....etc. long output
```

Window 2

```
$ sudo -u sawtooth settings-tp -v
[sudo] password for ahg2009:
[2019-08-04 11:42:06.578 INFO     core] register attempt: OK
```

Window 3.

````
$ sudo -u sawtooth /home/ahg2009/sawtooth-devmode-master/target/release/devmode-engine-rust -vvv --connect tcp://localhost:5050
TRACE | sawtooth_sdk::messag | Sending 37 bytes

{{After a while...}}

ERROR | devmode_engine_rust: | ReceiveError: TimeoutError
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to run the consensus engine and connect to the validator. Use Sawtooth version >= 1.1. The 1.0.5 version has the consensus module running inside the validator, so you can't connect it from outside as a separate process. It will be running dev mode consensus by default.

Comment: Thank you!  Then another question, the transactions I submit get stuck in pending state and nothing happens, if Sawtooth 1.0.5 runs consensus by default, why does it hang and doesn't do anything. (btw, I upvoted your question, but since I am new to stackoverflow, my upvote doesn't show, sorry)

Comment: Another question, thanks to your suggestion, I was able to start everything and Sawtooth processed transaction successfully. In this case I was starting everything in new windows. Now I want to start everything with nohup / &, so that I could log out and Sawtooth would continue to run:

nohup sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-validator -vv  &
nohup sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-rest-api -v &
nohup sudo -u sawtooth settings-tp -v &

This doesn't work. All three do not start python scripts. Do you know what am I missing now?  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like starting using systemctl as suggested on https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/sysadmin_guide/systemd.html works! Thanks a lot for your help!